Is there a simple way to execute dll methods as local system in windows from python script
I want to program a Python script that interacts with a DLL file. The DLL file needs to be run with Local System privileges.
My approach:
I am using the ctypes library in Python to interact with the DLL file. I encountered an ACCESS_DENIED error and found that I need to run the function with Local System privileges.
I am aware of creating a Windows service to handle this, but is there a more lightweight solution (e.g., a Python library)?
I didn’t try anything because I wanted the community’s opinion on this topic.
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)
lib.some_function()


Your Python process runs under a certain user account that can not be changed once it has been started. If you want to execute a DLL function with different permissions you have to create a new process, e.g. starting your python process a second time with Local System privileges.
